# Hawtio "Dashboard" tab not appearing

Tags: hawtio

I've downloaded and deployed the sample-1.4.45.war of hawtio in jetty_9.2.x server with pullOnStartup flag as true. I can see dashbaord json  files at .hawtio folder downloaded at home.user directory. The Dashboard tab is NOT appearing, however I get to see ActiveMQ, Camel, Wiki tabs.

I hope dashboard plugin is not missed in the downloaded war. The preferences does not show Dashboard plugin as well.

EDIT 1:
   The Dashboard tab appears when I deployed sample-1.4.37.war.

Comment: Are you saying that when you do the same kind of deployment, it works in 1.4.37 but fails in 1.4.45? In other words there is likely some bug in newer release that prevents you from seeing dashboards?

Comment: it seems to be a bug in 1.4.45. I dont know from which version this bug is available. I've raised an issue https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1926